# How to generate a cryptographically secure random integer within a given range in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, random, integer, plpgsql

### Problem

I want to write a PL/pgSQL function that generates a cryptographically secure random integer within a given range.

### Context

Many languages used for the application layer provide a built-in function to generate cryptographically secure random integers, which are useful for generating secrets or codes. For example, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandomintmin-max-callback) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.randbelow) have methods to produce such integers.

However, PostgreSQL does not have a built-in function for this purpose.

### Challenges

A proper implementation has to avoid introducing [modulo bias](https://research.kudelskisecurity.com/2020/07/28/the-definitive-guide-to-modulo-bias-and-how-to-avoid-it/) to the results. Otherwise, the generated integers may not be uniformly distributed. Some relevant PostgreSQL posts on StackOverflow appear to have solutions that do not account for modulo bias.

### Attempt

I based my attempt on the [Node.js implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/crypto/random.js) of its `crypto.randomInt` function. pgTAP tests for the below function pass, and I plotted the results of 2 million random integers between various ranges to check for modulo bias. However, I want to be cautious in case I overlooked any flaws or mistakes.

Does the below function require any tweaking? It takes two integer inputs, `low` and `high`, and returns a random integer in the range `[low, high)`.

```postgresql
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

CREATE FUNCTION random_int(low INT, high INT)
    RETURNS INT
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    STRICT
    AS $$
DECLARE
    -- The maximum value of a 4-byte signed integer.
    RAND_MAX INT := 2147483647; 
    rand_range INT;
    rand_limit INT;
    rand_bytes BYTEA;
    x INT;
BEGIN
    IF low >= high THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Low must be less than high';
    END IF;

    -- The range of random integers that can be generated.
    rand_range := high - low;

    -- The maximum value that can be divided evenly by rand_range.
    rand_limit := RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % rand_range);

    LOOP
        -- Generate 4 random bytes.
        rand_bytes := gen_random_bytes(4);

        -- Convert the 4 random bytes to a 4-byte signed integer, masking the sign bit to ensure a positive integer.
        -- 127 is '01111111' in binary, so the bitwise AND operation drops the sign bit from the first byte.
        x := ((get_byte(rand_bytes, 0) & 127) << 24)
            | (get_byte(rand_bytes, 1) << 16)
            | (get_byte(rand_bytes, 2) << 8)
            | get_byte(rand_bytes, 3);

        -- Accept the random integer if it is less than rand_limit to avoid modulo bias.
        -- We accept up to, but not including, rand_limit, to ensure x % rand_range is evenly distributed.
        -- For any x >= rand_limit, x % rand_range will be biased.
        -- Consider the contrived example where rand_range = 5, RAND_MAX = 12, and rand_limit = 12 - (12 % 5) = 10.
        -- x             : | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10       | 11        | 12       |
        -- x % rand_range: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 (bias) | 1  (bias) | 2 (bias) |
        -- The numbers 0, 1, and 2 are more likely to be generated than 3 and 4.
        -- To avoid this bias, we only accept x < rand_limit
        -- x             : | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
        -- x % rand_range: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
        -- Adding low to the result ensures the random integer is in the range [low, high).
        IF x < rand_limit THEN
            RETURN (x % rand_range) + low;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- If rand_range exceeds what can be represented by a 4-byte signed integer, PostgreSQL will raise an integer out of range error.
    -- Catch this error and raise a more informative exception.
    EXCEPTION WHEN numeric_value_out_of_range THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'The difference between high and low cannot exceed the maximum value of a 4-byte signed integer';
END;
$$;
```

### Results

```postgresql
SELECT random_int(1, 4);

-- Returns a random integer in the range [1, 4)
```

```postgresql
SELECT random_int(-4, 1);

-- Returns a random integer in the range [-4, 1)
```

```postgresql
SELECT random_int(-2, 2);

-- Returns a random integer in the range [-2, 2)
```

```postgresql
SELECT random_int(0, 2147483647);

-- Returns a random integer in the range [0, 2147483647)
```

```postgresql
SELECT random_int(-1, 2147483647);

-- Raises an exception
-- (high - low) > the maximum value for a 4-byte signed integer
```